# Upload optimized/resized image using GAE on cloud storage

Tags: php, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have made a simple app with a form which gets user info and their image, when they submit form it saves data on google datastore and image in google cloud storage.

To use cloud storage space efficiently i want to upload resized(smaller) image on cloud storage, but as of now i couldn't found a solution for that, because GAE doesnt allow local storage to process image(for resizing).

Can you suggest any solution to use GCS space efficiently?

one solution i tried is to upload the image again using resized url(getImageServingUrl) and then delete the primary/first image, but i think its not very efficient way to do this task, as it will use server processing time.

Comment: resize it in the browser before upload then or rezise it in GAE before sending it to the bucket.

Comment: can you explain it further, how to resize it in browser without server interaction, and how can i resize image in GAE?

Comment: http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-resize-image-proportionally-using-javascript.html http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php GAE comes with it's own image rezising tools in Python (PIL) I don't know about PHP.

Answer (score 0):

GAE now support ImageMagick (Version 1.9.18 - February 19, 2015) so you can use this extension to re size the image and then upload

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes

however if you need to get image re sizing at run time here is the way
object_image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($object_image_file,
                                            ['size' => 400, 'crop' => true]);